# Failed to open zip file (gradle dependency)

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, sdk

I am trying to build a simple program, but I get an error that a zip file failed to open and some gradle dependency cache corruption message.

I tried deleting the .gradle file and replacing it with one from a working project from another PC, but it didn't work also. Any ideas?

Comment: need more details can you include the results of `--stacktrace` build?

Comment: I had a similar problem, I hope this helps [gradle; failed to open zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45416840/there-is-no-android-device-showing-in-my-android-studio/45417586#45417586)