# There is no android device showing in my android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-2.3

I recently downloaded android studio 2.3.3. I am kind of a beginner in java programming, and I am proceeding with app building after some practice in programming using IntelliJ IDEA. I was learning using a video course, and in the video, an android model appears in the preview. When I downloaded it, there is no android showing, just an arrow. I tried making changes in the settings but none worked. I don't know why this is happening, but I am guessing it is happening because there is a problem with the zip file. I would appreciate if I got some help

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Try File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442901/gradles-dependency-cache-may-be-corrupt-this-sometimes-occurs-after-a-network

Comment: share your grade file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download gradle yourself and syn with android studio

For detailed step by step solution ,follow this YouTube video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u92_73vfA8M

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create a new AVD. Follow this guide https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html#createavd 
Then in the preview panel , right next to the android icon, null is written there. Click on it to choose the preview device.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was able to create the AVD